# Calendar failed to get the days names in different languages than English

Tags: java, localization, calendar

I'm trying to get the days of the week in German using the Calendar function getDisplayNames() with German locale.

```
Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
Map<String,Integer> displayNames = now.getDisplayNames(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.LONG, new Locale("de_DE"));
```

Instead I get the day of week names in English: Sunday, Monday, .... etc.
Am I doing something wrong or it simply doesn't work?
Maybe it got somthing to do with the toString() of my IDEA debugger console? I'm using the latest Intellij 12.1.2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use , `Locale.GERMAN` or use `new Locale("de")`, instead of `new Locale("de_DE")`

```
Map<String,Integer> displayNames = now.getDisplayNames(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, 
            Calendar.LONG, Locale.GERMAN);

Map<String,Integer> displayNames = now.getDisplayNames(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, 
            Calendar.LONG, new Locale("de"));
```

It is helpful to go through the Javadocs for [Locale(String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html#Locale%28java.lang.String%29) constructor, which says *"Construct a locale from a language code"*. The language code for German is **"de"** not **"de_DE".**

Comment: I tried that, although it's the same as writing    new Locale(de_DE) , the results are the same.

Comment: *although it's the same as writing new Locale(de_DE)* , no its not , please see the answer of Evgeniy Dorofeev.

Comment: Sorry I was mistaken, It works for both of your suggestions, thanks. but why the hall it doesn't works for "de_DE"?

Answer (score 2):

Locale is wrong, try

```
    Map<String, Integer> displayNames = now.getDisplayNames(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK,
            Calendar.LONG, new Locale("de"));
```

result

```
{Donnerstag=5, Mittwoch=4, Freitag=6, Dienstag=3, Samstag=7, Sonntag=1, Montag=2}
```

Locale with one arg means `Locale(String language)`

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using an instance of Calendar class you use the java.text.DateFormatSymbols to get information such as the month names, weekday names for a specific locale. Here is an example to get the weekday names in Germany.

```
String[] weekdays = new DateFormatSymbols(Locale.GERMANY).getWeekdays();
for (int i = 0; i < weekdays.length; i++) {
    System.out.println("weekday = " + weekdays[i]);
}
```